# How to efficiently add seconds place to date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a pandas data frame full of 1 second data of the form "10/23/2017 6:00". Each time appears 60 times in the file, and I'd like to know if there is an easy/efficient/smart way to add seconds to each row such that I get "10/23/2017 6:00:00, 10/23/2017 6:00:01 ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then add `second`s created by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('time').cumcount(), unit='s')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['10/23/2017 6:00'] * 60}) 

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('time').cumcount(), unit='s')
print (df.head(10))
                 time
0 2017-10-23 06:00:00
1 2017-10-23 06:00:01
2 2017-10-23 06:00:02
3 2017-10-23 06:00:03
4 2017-10-23 06:00:04
5 2017-10-23 06:00:05
6 2017-10-23 06:00:06
7 2017-10-23 06:00:07
8 2017-10-23 06:00:08
9 2017-10-23 06:00:09
```